# Java library for text and commenting mark up

Tags: library, java

I'm interested in building a text management software and I'm looking for ideas on the framework to use. I'm familiar with Java, and was looking at Swing and JavaFX, but I haven't seen the features I want so far. I'm not afraid of trying a non java approach.

I am interested in building a rich text editor that specifically allows selective text highlighting and commenting (similar to how MS Word does it). I know that JavaFX allows the former but I haven't found evidence of the latter).

Any ideas would be nice. Thanks!